# How would I compute the following finite sums in R coding?

Tags: r

What would the computations of these finite sums look like ? I've read a bit online but it seems that my code isn't getting me anywhere.
**Is someone able to show how the code should look and explain the functions used ?**

[image: Picture of the three sums...]

Comment: "it seems that my code isn't getting me anywhere." -- what code is that? Please include a [mcve]. Otherwise, this reads like an attempt to get Stack Overflow to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for a), you can follow the logic and calculate other two:

First, like a table, so you can see each result:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(i = rep(1:20,each=5),
               j = rep(1:5, times= 20))

data <- data %>%  mutate(calc = i^4/(3+j))
```

and here as a function:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
    calc = (i^4/(3+j))
    print(calc)
  }
}
```